A chess cartoon from 1981

I apologize for the bad scan; the club zine of mine where I found it is >40 years old, and was
badly printed even then. I doubt I can provide a better quality by a new scan.
I hardly know any Chinese beyond xiangqi=chinese chess, and of course I can't
Google translate myself if I don't even recognize the signs! Can you translate
the Chinese in the cartoon for me? (And: any idea about the source?)

小明 自称 “象棋 大王” ，遇上 ..... cannot recognize the others

I can only recognize 將軍，which means check in this case.

At the top, the title is "下象棋". The robot-like figure have the words "將軍" attached to it via a line. In the first of the bottom two lines, I can barely discern the words "小明", followed by a few spaces (or undiscernible characters), and then "自称", again followed by blank, and finally "大王" or "天王", but I'm not sure. On the second line, I can see "遇上". There seems to be another character before "遇上", but it's too blurred to identify exactly what it is. My guess is "者", although it doesn't make much sense that way. Following "遇上", there's a very blurred character that I think is either "例" or "傑". Then, I barely recognize the characters "可" and "化". However, again, I'm not so sure, and it doesn't make much sense. Anyways, this is what I'm able to discern. The rest is a blurred mess or worn out characters. Hope this helps.
